# set field as empty for mongo object using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm calling user.save() on an object, where I set user.signup_date = null;

```
user.first_name = null;
user.signup_date = null;

user.save();
```

But when I look at the user in the mongodb it still has the signup_date and first_name set...how do I effectively set this field as empty or null?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To remove those properties from your existing doc, set them to `undefined` instead of `null` before saving the doc:

```
user.first_name = undefined;
user.signup_date = undefined;

user.save();
```

Confirmed as still working in Mongoose 5.9.7. Note that the field you're trying to remove must still be defined in your schema for this to work.

Comment: Very nice answer save a lot of my time :)

Comment: What about if filed is an Array it is not wokring :(

Comment: @AnilYadav Array fields are handled specially by Mongoose and should always exist (but can be empty, of course).

Comment: IS this still a valid answer? I am using mongoose 5.5.11, mongo 3.6 and setting the field as undefined does not remove the field, it sets it to null

Comment: @faniva Yes, I just confirmed it's still working in 5.9.7. Note that the field you're trying to remove must still be defined in your schema.

Comment: @AnilYadav you can set an empty array for that case. `user.some_data = [];`

Answer (score 6):

Does it make a difference if you try the set method instead, like this:

```
user.set('first_name', null);
user.set('signup_date', null);
user.save();
```

Or maybe there's an error when saving, what happens if you do:

```
user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Does it print anything to the log?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to define a default value as `undefined` for these properties.

Something like the following:

`let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    default: undefined
  },
  signup_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: undefined
  }
})`

Comment: Necessary only on type:Array and type:Map, but great tip !!

Answer (score 1):

Just delete fields

```
delete user.first_name;
delete user.signup_date;
user.save();
```

Comment: You could try this after doing: `user = user.toObject()` first.

Answer (score 1):

On [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) (Schema Types), you can go to the `Arrays` explanation. There, it says this:

> Arrays are special because they implicitly have a default value of `[]` (empty array).

```
var ToyBox = mongoose.model('ToyBox', ToyBoxSchema);
console.log((new ToyBox()).toys); // []
```

> To overwrite this default, you need to set the `default` value to `undefined`

(*I've made an addition inside the `toys` element*)

```
var ToyBoxSchema = new Schema({
     toys: {
          type: [{
              name: String,
              features: [String]
          }],
          default: undefined
     }
});
```