# How to allow null field when updating in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Venue.update({_id : venue.id},                         
    {
      name : venue.name,
      'contact.phone' : venue.contact.formattedPhone                      
    }, {upsert: true}).exec()
```

In this code, if venue has no phone, Upsert operation is not done. How can I avoid this? I want to update that field if it is not null, but if null, just dont include that field.

Edit:

```
 Venue.update({_id : venue.id}, 
{
    name : venue.name,
    'contact.phone' : ((!venue.contact.formattedPhone)? 
                      '' : venue.contact.formattedPhone)                           
}, {upsert: true, safe:false}).exec()
```

This code works fine but this time, 'phone' fields are ''. What I want is, hiding the field if it is undefined.

Comment: Are you using `null`. If so, try `undefined` instead. I guess this thread might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636938/set-field-as-empty-for-mongo-object-using-mongoose

Comment: Can we do something like 'if formattedPhone == undefined than contact.phone is '' ?

Comment: Actually, I am Django guy who is currently transitting to node.js. I am experienced with mongoengine. I am not yet aware of mongoose much. I guess you too were a Django person switching to Node :)

Comment: Exactly:) I just moved to Node.js and Mongoose

Comment: I don't understand what behavior you're looking for.  Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: Let's say, one of a venue object in venues array has no formattedPhone data. So it is undefined. And the venue cannot be saved nor updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up your `update` object programmatically to not include `'contact.phone'` when not provided:

```
var update = {
    name : venue.name
};
if (venue.contact.formattedPhone) {
    update['contact.phone'] = venue.contact.formattedPhone;
}
Venue.update({_id : venue.id}, update, {upsert: true, safe:false}).exec();
```