# Update document with error: Cast to string failed for value undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a simple document with name (require), description (optional). In my model, I update a document with a valid id and I pass description with value undefined because I want to remove this property from document. However, I got following error:
**message=Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "description", name=CastError, type=string, value=undefined, path=description** . How do I remove description property on update when user does not provide description? Is it possible?

Thanks

```
/*jslint indent: 2, node: true, nomen: true*/

'use strict';

var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongooser = require('../../lib/mongooser');

// Schema

var schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    required: true,
    set: mongooser.trimSetter,
    trim: true,
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  description: {
    set: mongooser.trimSetter,
    trim: true,
    type: String
  }
});

// Export

module.exports = mongoose.model('Role', schema);
```

**// Role.js**

```
var update = function (model, callback) {
    var test = { name: 'Users', description: undefined };

    RoleSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(model.id, test, function (error, role) {
      callback(error, role);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping down to the native driver like so:

```
var update = function (model, callback) {
   RoleSchema.update({_id: model.id}, {$unset: {description: 1 }}, callback);
   });
};
```

Comment: is there anyway telling mongoose that here is my new data, update it using this so I don't have to set unset individual fields if they're missing? Thanks

Comment: You should have also described what is happening here instead of just dropping the piece of code . It could have helped more readers this way.

Answer (score 2):

If someone does not want to drop down to native driver, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320056/5947136

The issue here is using **type** as a key in Schema.

```
var schema = new Schema({
 name: {
    required: true,
    set: mongooser.trimSetter,
    trim: true,
    type: String, // <-- This is causing the issue
    unique: true
  },
  description: {
    set: mongooser.trimSetter,
    trim: true,
    type: String // <-- This is causing the issue
  }
});
```

Refer the above answer for a solution without the need for native driver.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that. For or extra clarity, using type: String will force mongoose to try and cast the whole object into a string and fail.