# Mongoose Schema Error: "Cast to string failed for value" when pushing object to empty array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a strange problem and cannot figure out what the problem is. The Error-message doesn't help.

I'm sending an "alarm" to the server and want to save this alarm to my "device" which already exist in the database.

The alarm object I send to the server looks like this:

```
{
  actionTaken: "none", 
  dateTime: "20152111191512", 
  difference: 4.88, 
  timestamp: 1448128894781
}
```

The Schema for the device is as follows:

```
var deviceSchema = new Schema({
   deviceId: {
        type : String,
        index : {
            unique : true,
            dropDups : true
        }
    },
    alarms : [ {
        timestamp : Number,
        dateTime : String, //yyyymmddhhss
        difference : Number,
        actionTaken : String, //"send sms"
    } ]
});
```

I load the device from the database (`deviceId` is set):

```
Thermometer.findOne({
        deviceId : deviceId
}, function(error, device){ 
   //error handling
   var now = (new Date().getTime());
   var nowDateTime = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/[-T\s:]/g, "");
   var newAlarm = {
       timestamp : now,
       dateTime : nowDateTime, // yyyymmddhhmmss
       difference : diff,
       actionTaken : "none"
   };
   device.alarms.push(newAlarm);  //EXCEPTION !

   //       device.save //doesn't get called
});
```

As you can see in the comment, I get an Exception/Error when I want to push the "newAlarm"-object to the alarms-array of my device.

The Error says:

> Cast to string failed for value `[object Object]` at path `alarms`

Error-Object:

```
   kind: "string",
   message: "Cast to string failed for value "[object Object]" at path "alarms"",
   name: "CaseError",
   path: "alarms",
   stack: undefined,
   value: {actionTaken: "none", dateTime: "20152111191512", difference: 4.88, timestamp: 1448128894781}
```

Do you have an idea?

For me it doesn't make any sense. The array and its content (object) is specified in the Schema. Why is there a string cast error with the whole object as value?

What I use:

```
"express": "3.2.6",
"express-session":"1.7.6",
"hjs": "*",
"mongoose": "4.0.5",
"nodemailer": "1.4.0"
```

---

**EDIT:** I don't want to use nested Schemas. It is also possible to do it with arrays. I do it with arrays in some other Schemas.

**EDIT 2**:
I added an property `lastAlarm` and do

```
device.lastAlarm = alarm;
```

but after that, thermometer.lastAlarm is still undefined... but alarm is an object. So is it possible that the device object is locked some how?

Comment: possible it will help you [--Link--](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858613/update-document-with-error-cast-to-string-failed-for-value-undefined)

Comment: I already found that but unfortunately didn't help

Answer (score 50):

Mongoose interprets the object in the Schema with key 'type' in your schema as type definition for that object.

```
deviceId: {
  type : String,
  index : {
    unique : true,
    dropDups : true
    }
}
```

So for this schema mongoose interprets deviceId as a String instead of Object and does not care about all other keys inside deviceId.

**SOLUTION:**

Add this option object to schema declaration `{ typeKey: '$type' }`

```
var deviceSchema = new Schema(
{
   deviceId: {
        type : String,
        index : {
            unique : true,
            dropDups : true
        }
    },
    alarms : [ {
        timestamp : Number,
        dateTime : String, //yyyymmddhhss
        difference : Number,
        actionTaken : String, //"send sms"
    } ]
},
{ typeKey: '$type' }
);
```

By adding this we are asking mongoose to use `$type` for interpreting the type of a key instead of the default keyword `type`

Mongoose Docs reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey

Comment: This was the problem in my case.

Comment: Thanks alot, what I did instead of this, I renamed my schema custom types into some different names such as type -> Atype

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind. My editor did not show it as a "keyword" so it was not obvious.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it is too late, but here mongoose is assuming that deviceId is not an object and it is of type String

```
deviceId: {
  type : String,
  index : {
    unique : true,
    dropDups : true
  }
},
```

SIMPLE SOLUTION:

```
deviceId: {
  type: {
    type: String
  },
  index: {
    unique: true,
    dropDups: true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 9):

I would declare alarm as its own schema and set the alarms property as an array of alarm aka [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). This will allow you to add validation to the alarm schema, etc. **NOTE**: Subdocuments don't get saved until the parent is saved.

```
var alarmSchema = new Schema({
        timestamp : Number,
        dateTime : String, //yyyymmddhhss
        difference : Number,
        actionTaken : String, //"send sms"

});

var deviceSchema = new Schema({
   deviceId: {
        type : String,
        index : {
            unique : true,
            dropDups : true
        }
    },
    alarms : [alarmSchema]
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Wow, 5 years late but I recently faced this problem. All you need to do is specify the type in an object for nested routes. So your code would change to:

```
var deviceSchema = new Schema({
   deviceId: {
        type : { type: String },
        index : {
            unique : true,
            dropDups : true
        }
    },
    alarms : [ {
        timestamp : {type: Number},
        dateTime : { type: String }, //yyyymmddhhss
        difference : {type: Number},
        actionTaken : { type: String }, //"send sms"
    } ]
});
```

So for nested objects, you'd need to use `field: {type: String}` and not `field: String`

Answer (score 0):

```
var deviceSchema = new Schema({
 deviceId: {
    type : String,
    index : {
        unique : true,
        dropDups : true
    },
    alarms : {type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Alarm' }]}
});

var alarmSchema = new Schema({
    timestamp : Number,
    dateTime : String, //yyyymmddhhss
    difference : Number,
    actionTaken : String, //"send sms"
});
```

I would recommend to make an own schema for the alarms. I think u cant define an array in a schema like you do.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner schema to solve this,

```
var SchemaObject = require('node-schema-object');

// Create custom basic type 
// Type can be extended with more properties when defined 
var NotEmptyString = {type: String, minLength: 1};

// Create sub-schema for user's Company 
var Company = new SchemaObject({
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  name: NotEmptyString
});

// Create User schema 
var User = new SchemaObject({
  // Basic user information using custom type 
  firstName: NotEmptyString,
  lastName: NotEmptyString,

  // "NotEmptyString" with only possible values as 'm' or 'f' 
  gender: {type: NotEmptyString, enum: ['m', 'f']},

  // Index with sub-schema 
  company: Company,

  // An array of Objects with an enforced type 
  workHistory: [Company],

  // Create field which reflects other values but can't be directly modified 
  fullName: {type: String, readOnly: true, default: function() {
    return (this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName).trim();
  }}
});

// Initialize a new instance of the User with a value 
var user = new User({firstName: 'Scott', lastName: 'Hovestadt', gender: 'm'});

// Set company name 
user.company.name = 'My Company';

// The date is automatically typecast from String 
user.company.startDate = 'June 1, 2010';

// Add company to work history 
user.workHistory.push({
  name: 'Old Company',
  startDate: '01/12/2005',
  endDate: '01/20/2010'
});

console.log(user.toObject());

// Prints: 
{ firstName: 'Scott',
  lastName: 'Hovestadt',
  gender: 'm',
  company: 
   { startDate: Tue Jun 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
     endDate: undefined,
     name: 'My Company' },
  workHistory: 
   [ { startDate: Wed Jan 12 2005 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
       endDate: Wed Jan 20 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
       name: 'Old Company' } ],
  fullName: 'Scott Hovestadt' }
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue in frontend when I was filling the login form then
like `dispatch({email , password});`
you can see above i wrapped up into `curly braces` , i just remove curly `{}` then it worked in my case.

If your facing this issue from frontend then try this