# I get this error "Cast to String failed for value \"{}\" at path \"body\"" When saving post data to my mongodb collection, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, model, postman

I can't save anything to my new mongodb collection because I keep getting this error

```
    "message": "Cast to String failed for value \"{}\" at path \"body\""
```

I've successfully used models to add data to my mongodb collections with no issue in the past, but I tried to create a new model today and when I decided to test it using postman I kept getting this error . I tried reading online but couldn't find an answer, please help.

Here's my schema for this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: String
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ticketStyle: {
    type: String
  },
  ticketStatus: {
    type: String
  },
  response: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }
});

const Ticket = mongoose.model("Ticket", ticketSchema);

module.exports = Ticket;
```

and here is the route

```
router.post("/support", (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  const sender = "admin";
  const ticketStyle = "userstyle";
  const ticketStatus = "pending";
  const newTicket = new Ticket({
    body,
    sender,
    ticketStyle,
    ticketStatus
  });
  newTicket
    .save()
    .then()
    .catch(error => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});
```

I want add these posts to my collection, but since the "body" key-pair is required and I keep getting this error I'm stuck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846939/mongoose-schema-error-cast-to-string-failed-for-value-when-pushing-object-to

Comment: Didn't really explain anything , I already saw this question being answered but still didn't answer my question. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Just figured the issue (clumsy mistake), this was due to an issue caused from how I decided to name my variables. I updated the schema and variable names and all worked as intended.

new route:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const sender = "admin";
  const message = req.body.message;
  const ticketStatus = "pending";
  const ticketStyle = "userTicket";
  const newTicket = new Ticket({
    sender,
    message,
    ticketStyle,
    ticketStatus
  });
  newTicket
    .save()
    .then(tickets => {
      res.redirect(req.originalUrl);
      console.log("Successfully saved to database");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
      console.log("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

And I also updated the schema name too.

```
const ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ticketStatus: {
    type: String
  },
  ticketStyle: {
    type: String
  },
  reply: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

The issue was from requesting the body data in the route as just req.body, not req.body.message so I guess the code was trying to save/use the whole JSON file as a string (I guess) .