# mongoose array saved in wrong order or got error 'Cast to string failed for value' if schema for array is defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, pug

i work on a productivity app with a feature that people can select several items from a list of predefined items (tasks) to build a set of personal daily tasks and optionally fill one input field to modify the duration of that selected task. 
in my 'user' mongoose schema i have 'tasks' array and when the user completes his/her tasks selection, list of his/her tasks will be saved under his user details and the default list will not be modified. my problem is that when a user selects some tasks and click 'save today's tasks', array 'tasks' with selected objects is saved in the database but instead key/values pairs are saved for each object, my app saves array with keys in one object and values in other object. here is sample of saved data:

```
// if defined in userSchema: 
// tasks: [] // just empty array

// what i get now:
"tasks": [
    {
      "title": [
        "Title 01",
        "Title 02",
      ],
      "duration": [
        10,
        20,
      ]
    }
  ]


// what i need:
"tasks": [
    {
      "title": "Title 01",
      "duration": 10
    },{
      "title": "Title 02",
      "duration": 20
    }
  ]

// if defined in userSchema: 
// tasks: [tasksSchema] // array of predefinied objects
// i got just error message
"error": {
    "message": "Cast to string failed for value \"[ 'Title 01', 'Title 02' ]\" at path \"title\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"[ 'Title 01', 'Title 02' ]\"",
    "value": [
      "Title 01",
      "Title 02"
    ],
    "path": "title",
    "reason": null
  }
```

and here is rest of my code (model, controller, view):

```
// my model
const tasksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tasks',
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  duration: {
    type: Number,
  },
});


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    tasks: [tasksSchema],
  }
  {
    timestamps: true,
  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// my controller
exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });

    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      req.body,
      { new: true, runValidators: true },
    ).exec();

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        error: 'no User found',
      });
    }

    return res.redirect('back');
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
      const messages = Object.values(err.errors).map((val) => val.message);
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        error: messages,
      });
    }
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: err,
    });
  }
};


// my view (pug/jade)
each item in user.tasksList || [] // this list is generated from a model 'Tasks'
  li.sortableItem.ui-state-default.list-group-item(value=item._id id=`id_${item._id}` name="tasks")
    span
      input#title(type='text' name="tasks[title]" value=item.title)
    span 
      input#duration.col-sm-2.input-sm.text-gray(type='number', name="tasks[duration]" value=item.duration)
```

what am I doing wrong?
many thnx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose Schema Error: "Cast to string failed for value" when pushing object to empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846939/mongoose-schema-error-cast-to-string-failed-for-value-when-pushing-object-to)

Comment: You might have `title: []` earlier for `tasksSchema`, make sure the data in your database matches what you want. Mongoose is trying to convert the values from the database to the types you have specified in the schema

Answer (score 0):

If the framework doesn't have a simple way to return these inputs as an array of objects, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of objects from the separate arrays before instantiating the user:

```
tasks = tasks[0].title.map((e,i) => ({"title":e,"duration":tasks[0].duration[i]}))
```