# How do I upload an array of mages using fect API

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous, fetch-api

I am trying to upload an array of images using my custom API (Node JavaScript), here I just want to save the file name to my database, and uploading of the file works just fine (the middleware which I created for uploading works just fine because I have tried using the same middleware in the **postman**).

When it comes to the actual JavaScript file it is not working and shows the following error:

> Cast to string failed for value "{ '0': {}, '1': {} }" at path "images", images: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { '0': {}, '1': {} } ]" at path "images"

Here is my code

```
const createProperty = ['city', 'propertyType', 'propertyName', 'images'];

const newProperty = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < myids.length; i++) {
  newProperty[i] = $(myids[i]).val();
}


newProperty[myids.length] = [document.getElementById('PropertyPhotos').files];

const data = {};
createProperty.forEach((id, index) => {
  data[createProperty[index]] = newProperty[index]
})


await createData(data);

// here is the CreateDate function

export const createData = async (data) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/v1/properties',
      data
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', 'Property Created Successfully');
    }
    console.log(res.data);
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
    console.log(err.response.data.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you should use JSON.stringify to cast the object to an String.

Comment: What is the value of newProperty and document.getElementById('PropertyPhotos').files? Do you want to insert / copy the image files and get a 2d array from it? Please use console logs or a debugger to identify where the issue arise and post the expected behavior of the code

Comment: what's in myids at athe time of iteration? Please show it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Mongo. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846939/mongoose-schema-error-cast-to-string-failed-for-value-when-pushing-object-to) and [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4181).

And to send files you need to use form-data, but I don't see it in your code.

```
const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "/filepath.pdf");
```

Comment: hello, i don't know but whenever i use formdata, my above function createData is not working like it is giving me null as data.. please help me with that

Comment: @AshishArjun show full code for data transfer on front and back